# Html alert box pop up on condition

Tags: python, html, css, django

In my django project, I want to build one function in my html page to show the alert box if some output from the view.py equals to some number. Like, after clicking the button, the view.py function do the calculation and give the output, and if the number equals to one set in the html function, it will show the alert. How could I fulfill it? Here's my code, I tried but cannot show the box.
Here's the button in html and it also shows the process output "number":

```
<form action="{% url 'xx:aaa' %}" method='GET'><button type='submit' onclick = "Warn();">start</form>
<p id="name"> number </p>
```

In the view.py function aaa will process the data and give one output number like the following.

```
def aaa(request):
    xxxx
    return number
    context = {"number": number}
    return render(request, "xxx/xxx.html", context)
```

In the html, I added one java script for the alert box processing.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var a = '0';
    document.getElementById('name').value = b;
         <!--
            function Warn() {
            if(a==b)
               alert ("This is a warning message!");
            }
         //-->
</script>
```

Comment: A lot more information is required for anyone to be able to help you. Are you using a Python web framework such as Django? Have you got any code other than what you've posted?

Comment: Yes. I used the django to build the web.

Comment: You need to provide what you have already tried. If you are not at the point where you are able to do that, then you should probably be starting with some online Django tutorials. Otherwise there's too much background to explain.

Comment: I just tried some script but still not work. I re-edited the question so you may see what's going on. Thx!

Comment: Why do you have HTML comments in your JavaScript? Also, it should be `if(a==b)` not `if(a=b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<p id="name"> number </p>
```

to

```
<p id="name"> {{ number }} </p>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var a = '0';
    var b = '{{ number }}';
    function Warn() {
        if(a == b)
        alert ("This is a warning message!");
    }
</script>
```